# Trying to make a frame disappear from an actionlistener

Tags: java, swing

I have a **private action listener class** in the same class that uses it and I'm trying to make the current class disappear and make a new class visible when the `JLabel` is clicked. The `JLabel` is added dynamically at runtime. I don't know how to refer to my class without using `this.setVisible()`. I get a `"cannot find symbol"` error from my netbeans IDE when I use it. Here is my code:

```
public class displayImage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static class tagListener extends MouseAdapter {
        public tagListener() {
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel text = (JLabel) e.getSource();
            displayImage display = new displayImage(text.getText());
            this.setVisible(false);
            display.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    //Creates new form displayImage
    public static String tagWord;

    public displayImage(String tag) {
        initComponents();
        tagWord = tag;
        JLabel labelTag = new JLabel();
        labelTag.setText(tagWord);
        labelTag.addMouseListener(new tagListener());
    }

    //...other methods
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The first was already stated by [Cyrille Karmann](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15273856/758280) above. The second is to pass in a reference to your `JFrame` to your `MouseAdapter`:

```
 private static class tagListener extends MouseAdapter
 {
  private final JFrame frame;

  public tagListener(JFrame frame) 
  { this.frame = frame; }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
  {
   JLabel text =(JLabel)e.getSource();
   displayImage display = new displayImage(text.getText());
   frame.setVisible(false);
   display.setVisible(true);
  }
 }

 public displayImage(String tag) 
 {
  /* snip */
  labelTag.addMouseListener(new tagListener(this));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made tagListener as an inner *static* class. Therefore it is just like another class and it doesn't share the `this` reference of the displayImage class.

Change the inner class definition to

```
private class tagListener extends MouseAdapter
```

and modify your call to setVisible to use <s>`tagListener.this`</s> `displayImage.this`, to specify which `this` you are refferring to:

```
displayImage.this.setVisible(false);
```

Some remarks: you should really use Java convention for class names: tagListener and displayImage should be TagListener and DisplayImage. Also, it is bad style to extends JFrame. Favor composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: `this` inside `tagListener` will always refer to `tagListener`. The OP will need to us `displayImage.this`, or just leave off the qualification, and then it will work.

Comment: yes, you're right, I was a bit too quick to answer. Amending right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{
    JLabel text = (JLabel) e.getSource();
    Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(text);
    window.setVisible( false );
    ...
}
```